# Removing an element from NSDictionary causes it to be deallocated prematurely

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

Full project can be seen here (for context: https://github.com/atlas-engineer/next-cocoa)

The following code returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
- (bool)windowClose:(NSString *)key
{
    NSWindow *window = [[self windows] objectForKey:key];
    [[self windows] removeObjectForKey:key];
    [window close];
    return YES;
}
```

The following code, however, works

```
- (bool)windowClose:(NSString *)key
{
    [[self windows] removeObjectForKey:key];
    return YES;
}
```

As does the following:

```
- (bool)windowClose:(NSString *)key
{
    NSWindow *window = [[self windows] objectForKey:key];
    [window close];
    return YES;
}
```

It is only somehow when you put them together that everything breaks.

For reference, I've provided the AutokeyDictionary implementation below, which is the value of `[self windows]` in the examples above

```
//
//  AutokeyDictionary.m
//  next-cocoa
//
//  Created by John Mercouris on 3/14/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Next. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AutokeyDictionary.h"

@implementation AutokeyDictionary
@synthesize elementCount;

- (instancetype) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setElementCount:0];
        _dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *) insertElement:(NSObject *) object
{
    NSString *elementKey = [@([self elementCount]) stringValue];
    [_dict setValue:object forKey: elementKey];
    [self setElementCount:[self elementCount] + 1];
    return elementKey;
}

- (NSUInteger)count {
    return [_dict count];
}

- (id)objectForKey:(id)aKey {
    return [_dict objectForKey:aKey];
}

- (void)removeObjectForKey:(id)aKey {
    return [_dict removeObjectForKey:aKey];
}

- (NSEnumerator *)keyEnumerator {
    return [_dict keyEnumerator];
}

- (NSArray*)allKeys {
    return [_dict allKeys];
}

@end
```

Lastly, for the record, turning on zombies does make the code work, though that is obviously not a solution.

Comment: @matt I removed the ```return``` and just left it as ```[_dict removeObjectForKey:aKey];``` and still, no luck.

Comment: @matt, I have not turned off ARC, but if there is a way to check if it is still enabled, I would be happy to oblige

Comment: "use of undeclared identifier retain", ARC must be therefore on, I'm tempted to turn it off, as it seems to be more trouble than it is worth

Comment: Your window's `releasedWhenClosed` property is probably defaulting to `YES`, which is likely to conflict with ARC's memory management. Set it to `NO`.

Comment: @matt you can clone the project here if you want to take a look: https://github.com/atlas-engineer/next-cocoa

server.m is what invokes this method, maybe it is causing problems being part of a block or something, not sure

Comment: @KenThomases that seems to have done the trick, I had to set the property, close the window, and then remove it from the dictionary! thank you for helping me debug this issue!

Comment: Just set it at creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your window's `releasedWhenClosed` property is probably defaulting to `YES`, which is likely to conflict with ARC's memory management. Set it to `NO` when you create the window.

Comment: Should this be considered a bug?

Comment: @matt I think it's a documentation bug that the incompatibility with ARC is not called out. As far as an implementation bug, it's hard to see how it could be corrected. Cocoa may or may not use ARC internally and it has to work for clients which may or may not use ARC (including clients which were built before ARC was even a thing). Personally, I've always been annoyed that `releasedWhenClosed` exists and always turn it off to get sane memory management semantics.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer ended up being the following sequence of code

```
- (bool)windowClose:(NSString *)key
{
    NSWindow *window = [[self windows] objectForKey:key];
    [window setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
    [window close];
    [[self windows] removeObjectForKey:key];
    return YES;
}
```

any other order of events and the object would be prematurely released.